# How to call a function on a div click, and proper use of a switch?

Tags: javascript, html, css, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a game where the user will be sent to new "floors", when the user click the button/div (clear the floor in the future) a new div "lights up" (turns black) but I'm can't seem to get it to work. So the idea is by clicking the div, it will call the function, which will raise the variable level by 1, and when the switch runs, it'll light up (turn the divs black) that many divs with the ids "floor1-9"

```js
var level = 1

function floor() {
  level += 1;
}
switch (floor) {
  case 1:
    if (level >= 1) {
      document.getElementById("floor1").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor1").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (level >= 2) {
      document.getElementById("floor2").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor2").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 3:
    if (level >= 3) {
      document.getElementById("floor3").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor3").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 4:
    if (level >= 4) {
      document.getElementById("floor4").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor4").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 5:
    if (level >= 5) {
      document.getElementById("floor5").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor5").style.color = "white";
    }
  case 6:
    if (level >= 6) {
      document.getElementById("floor6").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor6").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 7:
    if (level >= 7) {
      document.getElementById("floor7").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor7").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 8:
    if (level >= 8) {
      document.getElementById("floor8").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor8").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  case 9:
    if (level >= 9) {
      document.getElementById("floor9").style.color = "black";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("floor9").style.color = "white";
    }
    break;
  default:

}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.quizdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button:active {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

.level {
  height: relative;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.floor {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="quizdiv">
    <div onclick="floor()" class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <div class="floor" id="floor1"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor2"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor3"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor4"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor5"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor6"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor7"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floot8"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor9"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code a bit.

1. Moved the `switch` inside the `floor()` function
2. Changed `color` to `backgroundColor` instead.
3. Removed all `else`, I don't think it is necessary
4. Changed `floot8` to `floor8`
5. Changed `level = 1` to `level = 0`, so that the function will enter `case 1`

Not sure if this is what you want, but this lit all div up to the last floor. Since I went with your original format, I didn't bother to optimize the code

```js
var level = 0;

function floor() {
  level += 1;
  switch (level) {
    case 1:
      if (level >= 1) {
        document.getElementById("floor1").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      if (level >= 2) {
        document.getElementById("floor2").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      if (level >= 3) {
        document.getElementById("floor3").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 4:
      if (level >= 4) {
        document.getElementById("floor4").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 5:
      if (level >= 5) {
        document.getElementById("floor5").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    case 6:
      if (level >= 6) {
        document.getElementById("floor6").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 7:
      if (level >= 7) {
        document.getElementById("floor7").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 8:
      if (level >= 8) {
        document.getElementById("floor8").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    case 9:
      if (level >= 9) {
        document.getElementById("floor9").style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
      break;
    default:

  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.quizdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button:active {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

.level {
  height: relative;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.floor {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="quizdiv">
    <div onclick="floor()" class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <div class="floor" id="floor1"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor2"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor3"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor4"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor5"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor6"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor7"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor8"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor9"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things I see here, first is switch statement should be inside "floor" function and second, you can optimise your code a bit like below, you can obviously change '9' to whatever value you want -

```
function floor() {
  level += 1;
  for(let index = 1; index <= 9; index++)
     document.getElementById("floor" + index).style.color = index <= level ? "black": "white"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need huge case statements do simple as follows

```js
var floorDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("floor");
var level = floorDivs.length;

function floor() {

  //reset levels
  if (level === -1)
    level = floorDivs.length;

  if (floorDivs[level])
    floorDivs[level].style.backgroundColor = "white";


  if (floorDivs[--level])
    floorDivs[level].style.backgroundColor = "black";


}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.quizdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button:active {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

.level {
  height: relative;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.floor {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="quizdiv">
    <div onclick="floor()" class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <div class="floor" id="floor1"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor2"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor3"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor4"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor5"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor6"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor7"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floot8"></div>
    <div class="floor" id="floor9"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need a switch case for it. Append the value of `level` with `floor` and get the element

```js
var level = 1

function floor() {
  if (document.getElementById('floor' + level) !== null) {
    document.getElementById('floor' + level).style.background = "black"

  }
  level += 1;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.quizdiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}

.button {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button:active {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
}

.level {
  height: relative;
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.floor {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="quizdiv">
  <div onclick="floor()" class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="level">
  <div class="floor" id="floor1"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor2"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor3"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor4"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor5"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor6"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor7"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor8"></div>
  <div class="floor" id="floor9"></div>
</div>
```